# Getting Arithmatic Overflow Error while doing an average of numbers - MIPS assembly (MARS)!

Tags: assembly, mips, average, mips32, mars-simulator

I am trying to get an average of ten numbers entered into an array. I am getting an an arithmetic overflow at `add $a2, $a2, $a1`.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Help would be appreciated.

Also, I tried switching the limit to 2 integers just because it would not overflow so quickly. It is adding the addresses together, instead of the integers. This is my guess as to why it keeps overflowing. How would I change the addresses to the integers, though?

Here is my code.

```
.data
  nums:
    .word   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
  prompt:
    .asciiz  "Please enter 10 positive integers:\n"
  avg:
    .asciiz "Avg = "
  result:
    .asciiz "      "

.text
.globl main
  main:
li      $v0, 4
la      $a0, prompt
syscall

li  $t1, 10
la  $a1, nums

getnums:  
addi    $t1, $t1, -1  
li  $v0, 5  
syscall

sw      $v0, ($a1)
addi    $a1, $a1, 4
bnez    $t1, getnums

#avg  
move    $a2, $zero  
move    $t0, $zero
addi    $a1, $a1, -4    
getavg:   
lw  $t0, 0($a1)  
addi    $t1, $t1, 1       
add $a2, $a2, $t0   #arithmetic overflow      
addi    $a1, $a1, -4  
bne     $t1, 10, getavg  

li      $v0, 4
la      $a0, avg
div $a2, $a2, 10 
syscall

la  $a0, ($a2) 
li  $v0, 1
syscall

li  $v0, 10
syscall
```

(Edited to fix code formatting - RobertB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using `$a1` as a pointer to the current word in memory. But when you do `add $a2, $a2, $a1`, you're adding the contents of the *register* `$a1`, not the contents of the memory address it points to. It won't take many cycles of adding a 32-bit memory address value to itself, before you hit an overflow.

The missing link is the Load Word instruction that would get the contents of the memory location:

```
lw $t0, 0($a1)
```

That would load the contents of the memory location *pointed to* by `$a1`, into `$t0`.

Comment: Where exactly would you put that? I tried before the overflow but it doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: It's not just a matter of plugging in the one line of code. You need to do some restructuring of your code, so that instead of referencing $a1, you reference $t0 (in my example), which contains the contents of the memory address pointed to by $a1.

Comment: That is what I have been trying to do. :\ For hours, no matter what I try, all I keep getting is an address instead of an integer.

Comment: #avg
  getavg: 
  lw  $t0, 0($a1)
  addi  $t1, $t1, 1  
  add $a2, $a2, $t0 #arithmetic overflow 
  addi  $a1, $a1, 4
  bne   $t1, 10, getavg
  
  div $a2, $t0, 10
  li      $v0, 4
 la      $a0, avg
 syscall
 
 li $v0, 5
 la $a0, result($a2) 
 li $v0, 1
 syscall

Comment: Ugh, could I suggest you paste your updated code into your original post as an edit? Assembler is hard enough to debug one line at a time!

Comment: Updated, sorry about that.

Comment: I don't see `$a2` getting initialized. Could that be the problem?

Comment: move $a2, $zero correct? Still gives me an address-like number.

Comment: When I run a break to the initializing of a2/t0 the first number that gets loaded in lw is the ascii digits to my Please prompt string. So, it starts one over and ends one early.. If i enter 1-10(with the code changed for 10 digits), I get Please,10,....2

Comment: I fixed that part I'll update. I am still getting an address for the average, though.

Comment: At the last syscall, before exiting the O.S. is where it prints the address of $a0 instead of $a2.

Comment: Well, I think I finally got it running correctly. It printed 5, I tried all 100's, and got 100. Thank you for you time. It was much appreciated now I have to try to get it to calculate max, min, and print the inputs, which I have already reversed into binary and hexadecimal.